# How to securely display HTML encoded data stored in a database

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using C#, ASP.NET MVC version 5 with Razor. I need to display a large number of Word files in a browser. It seems simplest to save the Word files as HTML, store in a database and then read them from the database and display as required.

I can use `@Html.Raw` to display them, but are there any security implications, cross-site scripting for example?

I know that the content of the Word files are safe.

Comment: You need to better define what is "secure" for you. Looks like you could do just that what you intend, but could make sure that no document contains "<script" (or extend this with regex to wrap around whole <script .+>.+</script>. That would prevent any possible script injection attack, but still if i.e. html contains resources like images, it could still make requests to other web sites that could track your user activity. You need to decide if that is acceptable or not.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed something like that, just needed a second thought